# Open terminal and run a command from automator to open two tabs and run a command

Tags: macos, terminal, automator

What I want to do is run an automator script. Where what happens is it opens terminal with two tabs and each tab and ssh onto root@192.168.0.1  and root@ssh@192.168.0.2; how would you do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To complement [Chris Page's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33972026/45375):

**If you want both Terminal tabs to be in the *same* window**, things get tricky: a long-standing limitation of Terminal's AppleScript API is the inability to programmatically create a new tab in an *existing* window.

You can work around the problem with GUI scripting; while the following handler, `makeNewTab()`, is reasonably robust, it requires prior one-time authorization for assistive access - see the comments on the handler below.

<sup>Note that authorizing generic execution environments such as Terminal.app and Automator.app for assistive access implies that *any* script run by them will have these privileges.</sup>

If you want more control over the tab creation process, such as the ability to assign a specific profile (appearance and behavior settings), see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12147804/45375), and an application of it at the bottom of this answer.

```applescript
(*
  Creates a new tab in Terminal's front window and optionally executes a shell command,
  if <shellCmdToRun> is a nonempty string.

  Note:
    * This handler effectively clicks the menu item that creates a new tab and
      therefore requires assistive access:
      The application running this handler - e.g., Terminal.app, Script Editor.app, 
      or Automator.app - must be added to the list at
      System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility,
      using admin credentials.
    * This handler activates Terminal first, which is required for it to work.

  Caveat: 
    If there's no front window or if all windows are currently minimized, the
    tab is created in a *new* window.

  Examples:
    my makeNewTab("") # open new tab (without executing a command)
    my makeNewTab("ls") # open new tab and execute shell command `ls`
*)
on makeNewTab(shellCmdToRun)
    tell application "Terminal"

        # Note: If Terminal is not frontmost, clicking the new-tab menu item invariably 
        # creates the tab in a *new* window.
        activate

        # Find the File menu by position and click the menu item whose keyboard shortcut is
        # ⌘T - this should work with any display language.
        tell application "System Events" to ¬
            tell menu 1 of menu item 2 of menu 1 of menu bar item 3 of menu bar 1 ¬
                of application process "Terminal" to click (the first menu item ¬
                whose value of attribute "AXMenuItemCmdChar" is "T" and ¬
                value of attribute "AXMenuItemCmdModifiers" is 0)

        # If specified, run a shell command in the new tab.
        if shellCmdToRun ≠ missing value and shellCmdToRun ≠ "" then
            do script shellCmdToRun as text in selected tab of front window
        end if

    end tell
end makeNewTab
```

---

If you're willing to install [my `ttab` CLI](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ttab), you can make do without AppleScript altogether, and instead run the following from a `Run Shell Script` Automator action:

```
# Create tab in new window (-w) and run specified command.
ttab -w ssh root@192.168.0.1       

# Create additional tab in same window, with specific settings.
ttab -s Grass ssh root@192.168.0.2
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use the **Run AppleScript** action to run a script like:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        do script "ssh root@192.168.0.1"
        do script "ssh root@192.168.0.2"
    end tell

    return input
end run
```

Terminal’s `do script` command creates a new terminal window and sends the given command string to the shell. Note that if you want to send additional commands to the same terminal, store the result of the `do script` command in a variable—it will be a reference to the terminal that was created and you can use it with the `in` parameter of the `do script` command to send more commands to that terminal.