# write command script to open terminal with two tabs in same window of macbook os

Tags: command-line, terminal, automation, applescript

I have tried below script but it opens two new terminal window.

I am not getting how to **open two tabs in same terminal window**.

```
osascript <<END
tell application "Terminal"
  set currentTab to do script ("cd projects/cricket")
  set currentTab1 to do script ("cd && cd projects/football")
  do script ("rails server -p 3000") in currentTab
  do script ("rails server -p 5000") in currentTab1

end tell

END
```

saved above file as run.command and made it executable

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171725/open-new-terminal-tab-from-command-line-mac-os-x ?

Comment: @Mihir like this only but I want to execute above commands.. Im not getting that in answer suggested by you