# Opening several MacOS terminals and running a command on each tab

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, applescript

Every time I get to work I have to startup 6 local servers. It would be amazing to have one script that starts up these processes in their respective tab.

So it would come done to something like:
echo 'Starting server'
*open new tab*
*cd to directory (ex. /project company/back-end/server))*
*run startup command (ex. node server.js)*

I'm quite new and the examples with bash or applescript didn;t work for me.

BTW: there's an space in the cd directory names, I read that it's different then?

Comment: Spaces should be backslash-escaped on the command line like `/project\ company/back-end/server`. You can have these commands run in the background via `&` or `cron`, run in a bunch of viewable terminals with something like `tmux`,  via one script that does everything else, or a host of other options. You question as it stands is too vague to be a good question on this site; you would be better off doing some research and showing what you've tried before posting here, and defining your question in a much more narrow manner.

Comment: Not exactly tabs, but I feel like tmux can handle something like this. Once you familiarize yourself with a few basic commands, you would be able to use a script such this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/355165/226626

Tmux primer (not really neccesary to set up a workflow like this): https://tmuxcheatsheet.com/

Comment: this could be help you: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171725/open-new-terminal-tab-from-command-line-mac-os-x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171725/open-new-terminal-tab-from-command-line-mac-os-x)

Comment: Question: do you need the terminal windows open for some particular reason? It seems to me it would be easier to run the commands from AppleScript in the background, and skip the whole 'Terminal' headache.

Comment: @TedWrigley yeah, having them open shows logs and errors